# after add 1 record, all of the ID increase

Tags: java

I'm trying to have a auto increment of the ID.

But my problem is I got 3 records here. But when I add another record and try to display all the record, all the ID of other record will increase become the newest ID. How to solve it?

[image]

What is the problem?

[image]

Is there any problem with my Singer class?

```
public class Singer{

private static int id=0;
public String name;
public String country;
public String musicCategory;
public String bio;

public Singer(){
    this(null,null,null,null);
}

public Singer(String name, String country, String musicCategory, String bio){
    
    this.name=name;
    this.country=country;
    this.musicCategory=musicCategory;
    this.bio=bio;
    id++;
}
//getter
public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getCountry(){
    return country;
}

public String getMusicCategory(){
    return musicCategory;
}

public String getBio(){
    return bio;
}

//setter
public void setId(int id){
    this.id=id;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public void setCountry(String country){
    this.country=country;
}

public void setMusicCategory(String musicCategory){
    this.musicCategory=musicCategory;
}

public void setBio(String bio){
    this.bio=bio;
}
}
```

Comment: You only have id and it's static: `private static int id=0`.  You should rename that to `lastId`, and each instance of the class should have a `public int id;` field.

Comment: How are you adding a record? Show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` field is static. Static fields are unique per type(class) and not unique per instance. The static variable is commonly shared by all instances. Every time you create an instance, you are incrementing the id for all the `Singer` objects.
You need to have another non-static id that is unique per instance:

```
private static int previousId = 0;
private int id; // non-static

public Singer(String name, String country, String musicCategory, String bio){
    this.id = ++previousId;
    this.name=name;
    this.country=country;
    this.musicCategory=musicCategory;
    this.bio=bio;
    
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much ! Sorry did not realize about this.